# non-English characters displayed incorrectly until CommandButton is clicked

Tags: excel, vba

I have excel file with some ActiveX CommandButtons integrated directly into worksheet. Their Captions written in non-English language with some non-English characters. Problem I encountered that some of these characters are not displayed correctly until CommandButton is clicked (picture below):

[image]

Have anybody encountered similar problem? I tried changing fonts and character size, but that did not helped.

I cannot provide any code since I have no idea where to start. Maybe it is possible to somehow fake constant focus to them?

Answer (score 1):

Laba diena!

If you created these with ActiveX Command buttons, you should be able to view the name and caption properties by either 1) clicking once, then right-clicking to get a menu with properties as a choice or 2) double-clicking to get a click event started in the visual basic editor.  From there you should see what's listed as the caption for the button.

In the button properties there should be a "TakeFocusOnClick" property that defaults to True.  I don't know if it will fix your problem, but try changing it to false.  I couldn't emulate your exact problem, so I couldn't tell.
sėkmės!

Comment: Laba diena! Ačiū už atsakymą. Unfortunately, but that did not helped (but changing property to False removed doted line on click and gave cleaner look, upvote for that idea). While trying your suggestion I noticed, that if I go to `Properties>Font` and change Script to Western and then to Baltic again letters are displayed correctly for whole session, but as soon as I close and reopen workbook, Baltic letters displayed incorrectly again. Now I am thinking if it is possible to write macro which on startup automatically change script to Western and Back to Baltic again.